# Image is too noisy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

This too noisy after rendering, I tried to give it more samples up to 500, it changed a little, higher resolution also helped, but still it is too noisy, Caustics on nor off don't make a real difference, bounces are set to 1024. I really don't know what else I can do, and haven't found an answer anywhere.

[image]

Detail:

[image]

This is the result.

[image]
This picture was taken in Rhinoceros via Vray, same scene, settings as same as it was possible, but you can see no noise here. And this is the result I would like to achieve in blender too.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend? Perhaps we can find if there is some setting which could be adjusted

Comment: Your issue is refered tp to as **FIREFLIES** related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-decrease-fireflies-when-using-cycles-glass-shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the direct clamp and indirect clamp value to 3, it's in the Properties Panel/Render Properties/Samples panel.
Also try setting multi importance samples higher, it helps if you are using skybox or HDRI.
And finally try to increase your rendering samples even higher.

Comment: I have experienced, that I can do great renders with 100 samples, there I tried also 1000 and the result was just slightly better. Clamp value works also a little, and it makes the image darker. Multiple importance is everywhere on and now also on 1024. Will try to render and post the result.

Comment: got the result, still noisy, but the fireflies are gone, i guess that more samples will do the trick in this case. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

Try some of the clamp and glass shader suggestions in the article. Hope that helps!

Too noisy means fire-flies FYI :)

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Link-only answers are discouraged, as if the page at then end of the link is changed or removed the answer is lost. Could you add some more info to your answer?

Comment: this is not only fire-flies ;) if you open it and look on it, there are areas of noise, it is because of the lights, So I guess your link even if it worked would not help me.