# How to fix grains within render?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I've been trying forever to find solutions to this problem.
When I render, my scene gets grainy under the influence of light and after searching the internet I can't find a proper solution:
 [image] 
I want to know how to get rid of the grainy-ness on the diffuse object under the light, and also the two random white pixels. I'm using Cycles, my sampling is at 4000 and my light bounces are set the limited global illumination.

P.S. Can anyone tell me how my GTX 1070 took 5 minutes to render this (and/or how I can render more efficiently)?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39391/how-to-reduce-noise-in-a-dark-cave-scene

Answer (score 0):

Turning up the AA Samples helps.
[image: AA-Samples]
25 is decent, higher is better.
Glossy and Transmission tend to be noisy, so I turn those up.

I usually click render, then go watch TV.
If I come back an it looks OK, then I stop the render.
It only ever goes through all 64 passes if I fall asleep.

[image: LightPaths]