# weird rendering artifacts in blender 2.9

Tags: rendering

so here i am, making a meme render in blender 2.9, just updated today from 2.81 and found this in my test render[image: odd lines in the render]

and im not sure how to fix it, im new to using this software and not sure what im doing but i never had this issue before, and also before i go through updating my drivers i want to make sure of what it is, i also am not aware of anyone who has solved this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at this post? Maybe your sample size is too low: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61248/rendered-image-showing-grains                    you can also use the denoiser or switch to eevee to render faster.

Comment: the sample size is 480 which for a test render is just fine, but its the lines that are the issue as i have put them up to 1k and they still appear, in the mean time im just going back to 2.83 but i would like to use 2.9 its just im not working on getting renders to have lines on them.