# I have some strange noisy places in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, optimization

[image]

When i render I'm getting strange places which are grainy, only on the right side of the picture. Would appreciate help.

Comment: Those are not "blocky" they are called "Fireflies". Possible duplicate of [How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see this grainy fields also on the left side of the picture, only maybe not that obvious. Are you using Cycles? => more samples should help.

Could also happen in the image compression for example if you save as .jpeg => try an uncompressed image format

EDIT: 200 samples are still not very much. You get clean image at this size from about 500 samples. Especially for renderings with very small or weak lightning, transparencies and reflections Cycles gets very noisy.

Anywhay you should read [this](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/) article where further omptimzing possibilities are explained

Comment: I changed format to tif and buffed samples from 128 to 200. Image became bit brighter but those places remained. I watched how the rendering goes and it looks like it renders those places but they are not changing.

Comment: Please read the Edit of my answer