# sparkling shadow, sun glass shader reflects the plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: sparkling shadow GLASS material]
[image: Settings have no node with ADD VALUE CLAMP]

attached please find an example. thank you for Support in advance. And thanks to members Rivera and Cegato. How can I remove the SPARKLING orange shadow (Plane remove reflecting?)

Comment: These are called fireflies and are generally the result of low amount of rendering samples. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Comment: Not an answer, but your node tree has a few problems: don't use an add shader for anything that are not shaders (green input should be connected to a green output), use the layer weight directly as a factor for the mix shader. The last Mix shader on the chain has an unplugged socket, what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Answer (score 1):

Please find the nodetree which solved the problem. I don`t know why it exactly works because try a lot and finally I removed the cast shadow of sun and the fireflies are gone. Sorry, for not more knowledge answer as beginner. Thanks a lot and have a great time
                                                                                                             [image]