# Strange rendered texture

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an issue with cycles render where it doesn't seem to be rendering fully the eye just look dotty. 
[image]

Here is a image of the rendered mesh and eye. I would prefer if it can be fully rendered instead of a dotty look. How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3u9upxna0um4mc/outhauscharacterdesigns.blend?dl=0 Link to my file if you want

Comment: Those are fireflies probably caused by caustics from the glass material. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Comment: To upload files please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles/2565#2565

Comment: Also when uploading files make sure that you pack the textures along with the blend file.

Comment: Yeah those are related, thank you. As for the upload files, okay I will next time. Just that last time I tried to upload another file through that, it had a mb limit.