# How to clean white spots on an image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, noise-reduction

I was watching a tutorial on making a cup, (link in comment) and towards the end, he says make Clamp 0.98 in order to remove white spots on the image.

I added 0.99 to Clamp Direct (2.78c) and I still get the white spots on the image, and no clean cup and bottom on render. The image looks like this,

[image: Rendered Image]

while his image looks like this

[image: His Image]

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of my settings in the comment.

Comment: link to the video: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChPle-aiJuA)

Ah cr*p, the screenshot images didn't upload to imgr.

Comment: Do request if you need the images of the settings.

Comment: Increase the amount of samples and see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Comment: I used the same samples as he did (250) but he still got a better noise free image. How?

Comment: Do you need any additional info?

Comment: It is probably youtube video compression fooling you into thinking the image is clean. Anyway if at the same amount of samples yours is noisy increase the amount of samples.

Comment: Yep, tried that (went up to 2000) and my 1050 Ti kicked my speaker out and back in, black screened, and shut blender. Whoops my i5, re tried, and it got this gorgeous image processing, with a blue reflection of the plane below and just as I was about to screenshot for safe keeping, it crashed Blender again. There were fireflies inside the cup. Maybe I need more samples.

Should I consider upgrading the CPU? i5 7400 @ 3 Ghz, or just shut Chrome down?

Edit: Wait, the old image had a blue reflection?

Comment: Also, can compression make so much of a difference? The insides of the cup look much better than mine did @2000 samples.