# Lighting and Cycles Noise and artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Can anyone help me on how I could make a better render to my scene? No matter what I do it always shows these fireflies and never render with the quality i need... [image]

I´m using filmic color management, 128 samples (and even when I increase this number I still get noise), and Filter Glossy: 2.
For lighting, I´m using a sky hdr.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles