# Granular quality on the render of transparent objects

Tags: rendering, transparency

[image]I am getting a 'granular quality' on the render of transparent and translucent objects within a building interior. Does anyone know of a way to avoid this in order to achieve a smooth, sharp, high resolution render? Tips, suggestions or links most welcome.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do:

1. Turn up samples, a lot
2. Turn on the denoiser
3. Use D-Noise https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/
4. Disable refractive and maybe reflective caustics, in light passes tab