# Bad dotted render

Tags: rendering

[image: Render with 32 samples]

Can't understand what the problem is, the number of whit

Comment: If you use Cycles they could be caustics.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles