# How do I get rid of orange specs in my render in blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to get better at using blender by following a tutorial i watched i followed everything but my render has orange specs i tried higher samples changing lights. i need help. these aren't white fireflies due to textures they are orange specs that don't go away no matter what.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

Comment: They do look like fireflies. Are you using Cycles in 2.8? HDR? what is your material Nodes? The Rocks and Sand also appear to have the same issue. What have you set your Samples to? You can change it to 0 and watch the rendering continue until you are happy. Can you post the .blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/