# Animation artifact issue

Tags: animation

Hope everyone is safe.
I have created this small test animation. A clean raptor and a HDRi in the scene that's it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8dvulisy02nfs9/0001-0060.mp4?dl=1

As you can see i have those strange sparkles, artifacts on the skin and eyes. I thought it was the denoiser but when i test without i have the same issue.
I use cycle , 128 samples render + motion blur. I go to png first then mp4. But already when i play the PNG i have the issue.
I have this issue in all my animations!
Thanks for your help!
Cheers

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the hdri (wide dynamic range) and the material setup this could be [fireflies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1703/30849) or noise (improve your sample settings possible with [branched path tracing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpTm-cwSuz4)).

Comment: Thanks man! I will try that! thanks again the quick feedback!