# I get white pixels all over the rendered image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

So I'm new and I'm using Cycles rendering.
The problem is that when I render I get white particles all over the image.
I learned that MIS helps out with that, but I don't know how to apply it as I am using Emission on material.(I am not using any lamps and I know that they have this option)[My blender view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrTOM.png)
currently using 2.79 as I find it easier to navigate.[image: Rendered image]
Is it possible to fix it with nodes? or at least someway else.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703

Comment: Not that the proposed duplicate answers do not address the real problem: fireflies. More samples won't necessarily clear fireflies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Properties** window, **Rendering** tab, **Sampling** panel, you'll find the **Clamp** options. Try to change the **Clamp Direct** to 1 or to play with it a little bit.

EDIT: I just noticed there is a bulb (glass material). Maybe you'll have to play with the **Clamp Indirect** too.

[image]

Explanation of what happens:
These white pixels are called "lucky rays". It happens in Cycles when you have many reflections. They are light rays that arrive to the camera in less bounces than the others, so their light is more powerful.
Playing with the clamp values you clamp the light to a value, so this rays are not so powerful anymore.

Comment: Thanks it worked <3

Comment: A common term used to describe those bright pixels in rendering is "fireflies".