# How to get rid of fireflies caused by glass material?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm using cycles render for glass shader. I'm using GPU compute for faster rendering in the viewport. I have bumped the samples to 100000, and still getting fireflies on the glass. I have tried various set ups from YouTube tutorials, but the fireflies insist showing on the glass sphere.

[image]

**Q:** How to get rid of the fireflies in this case?

Comment: Related or dupe: [How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0):

**Increase your clamping values.**

Within Blender's render settings tab, there are two values: Clamp direct and Clamp indirect. In essence, a higher value for these will reduce fireflies at the cost of realism by lowering the values of very high intensity pixels. With your samples already at such a high value, a slight amount of increasing the clamping could definitely reduce your fireflies.

(side note: some of your fireflies appear to be a result of noise, you can try using the new denoise node in the compositor.)