# How do I stop noisy renders in blender?

Tags: rendering

I'm new to blender and I can't seem to work out why when I render out anything it is really noisy. I've tried turning up the samples but it still doesn't really do anything, I must be doing something wrong, I'm not sure. [image]

here's something I quickly set up to show the problem, this is at 512 samples. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use the denoiser for that matter.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703

Comment: 512 samples is not that much... Try 2k samples or just denoise the image.